# Add gradient to colorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, gradient

Newby here. I found a great template for technical reports here . .

http://www.latextemplates.com/template/stylish-article

[image]

I would like to change the background color of the abstract and section headings to a vertical gradient.

The relevant section of code in the template appears to be here . .

```
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\twocolumn[{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%    

\vskip-36pt%
{\raggedleft\small\sffamily\bfseries\@JournalInfo\\\@Archive\par}%
\vskip20pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont \@PaperTitle\par}%
\vskip10pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@Authors\par}%

\vskip18pt%
\fcolorbox{color1}{white}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\centering%

% HERE IS THE SECTION I WANT TO CHANGE
\colorbox{Color2!10}{%

\parbox{\textwidth-4\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
\ifx\@Keywords\@empty%
\sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract%
\else%
\sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract\\[4pt]%
\textbf{\keywordname}\\\@Keywords%
\fi%
}%
}%
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Try with `tikz`

Comment: This is possible with `tcolorbox` package. And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: It's probably easiest to do this by converting the `\colorbox` commands into `tcolorbox` environments, which accept TikZ drawing commands as styling options. Refer to Section 7.1 of the [manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox), particularly the `/tcb/interior style` key.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option using the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package to define a color box with a vertical shading; since the class uses `titlesec` to format the titles, the necessary redefinition for sections is quite simple

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\large\sffamily\bfseries\filcenter}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\begin{mybox}[center upper,colupper=color1]\arabic{section}.~#1\end{mybox}}
  []
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\large\sffamily\bfseries\filcenter}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\begin{mybox}[center upper,colupper=color1]#1\end{mybox}}
  []
```

where `mybox` is the newly defined box; a redefinition of `\maketitle` is also required to use the shading for the box.

Change the colors for the shading (inside the `\fill` in the definition of `mybox`) according to your liking:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.55cm}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.75pt}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,0,90} % Color of the article title and sections
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,20,20} % Color of the boxes behind the abstract and headings

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,colorlinks,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=color2,citecolor=color1,linkcolor=color1,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}

\JournalInfo{Journal, Vol. XXI, No. 1, 1-5, 2013}
\Archive{Additional note}

\PaperTitle{Article Title}

\Authors{John Smith\textsuperscript{1}*, James Smith\textsuperscript{2}}
\affiliation{\textsuperscript{1}\textit{Department of Biology, University of Examples, London, United Kingdom}}
\affiliation{\textsuperscript{2}\textit{Department of Chemistry, University of Examples, London, United Kingdom}}
\affiliation{*\textbf{Corresponding author}: john@smith.com}

\Keywords{Keyword1 --- Keyword2 --- Keyword3}
\newcommand{\keywordname}{Keywords}

\Abstract{\lipsum[1]}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
  freelance,
  frame code={},
  interior code={
    \fill[top color=color2!45,bottom color=color2!5,middle color=color2!15]
      (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);
  }
  outer arc=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0pt,
  nobeforeafter,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
  #1
}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\large\sffamily\bfseries\filcenter}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\begin{mybox}[center upper,colupper=color1]\arabic{section}.~#1\end{mybox}}
  []
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\large\sffamily\bfseries\filcenter}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\begin{mybox}[center upper,colupper=color1]#1\end{mybox}}
  []

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\twocolumn[{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vskip-36pt%
{\raggedleft\small\sffamily\bfseries\@JournalInfo\\\@Archive\par}%
\vskip20pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont \@PaperTitle\par}%
\vskip10pt%
{\raggedright\color{color1}\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@Authors\par}%
\vskip18pt%
\fcolorbox{color1}{white}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\centering%
\begin{mybox}
\ifx\@Keywords\@empty%
\sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract%
\else%
\sffamily\textbf{\abstractname}\\\@Abstract\\[4pt]%
\textbf{\keywordname}\\\@Keywords%
\fi%
\end{mybox}
\vskip4pt%
\begingroup%
\raggedright\sffamily\small%
\footnotesize\@affiliation\par%
\endgroup%%
}%
}%
\vskip25pt%
}]%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\flushbottom
\maketitle
%\tableofcontents
%\thispagestyle{empty}

\section*{Introduction}

%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-3]
 and some mathematics $\cos\pi=-1$ and $\alpha$ in the text\footnote{And some mathematics $\cos\pi=-1$ and $\alpha$ in the text.}.

\section{Methods}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]